# Principal Branch of Complicated Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, branch-cuts

What is the principle branch of the complex function $\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{1-z}$? I know that it can be written as follows:

$$e^{\frac{1}{2}(\ln{|1+z|}+i\arg{(1+z)})} + e^{\frac{1}{2}(\ln{|1-z|}+i\arg{(1-z)})}$$

But now I'm confused how to find the principal branch from here; I think I have to find the values of $z$ such that neither $\arg$ is multivalued, but I'm not sure. How do you find the principal branch from here?

Comment: The principal branch of the square root is the branch obtained by removing the negative real numbers and choosing the values such that $\sqrt{1}=1$. So, for $\sqrt{1+z}$ that would remove the real numbers with $1+z<0$. This is, $z<-1$. For $\sqrt{1-z}$ it would remove the real numbers with $1-z<0$. This is, $z>1$.

Comment: To choose the the value in the form $\sqrt{z}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(z)}$, to get the value $\sqrt{1}=1$, you would choose the branch of $\ln$ for which $\ln(1)=0$. This determines uniquely the values on the plane with the two rays that we removed above.